# how to Print some values from a 3d array

Tags: java, arrays, 3d

i have this array here and i tried to print some of the info i need but it print it all

```
int customer=1
int Item=2

     CPR[customer]=new int[Item][2];

     for (int i = 0; i < Item; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j <2; j++) {
                System.out.print((CPR[customer][i][j]=scanner.nextInt());
```

it's equal to the Scanner which is reading from a file  and its output like this

```
2 8
4 5
```

i just need to print the 8 and 5 how can i get it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` statement to print only the second item:

```
int customer=1
int Item=2

CPR[customer]=new int[Item][2];

for (int i = 0; i < Item; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <2; j++) {
        CPR[customer][i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
        if (j == 1) {
            System.out.print(CPR[customer][i][j]);
        }
     }
}
```